# Memory management when using IBOutlet/NIBs

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, interface-builder, nib

My app is nearly finished and I have been Profiling it using Instruments. I'm checking out retain counts of various objects.

I have been careful to release any objects which I have called alloc on, and these don't seem to be leaking - so thats cool.

However, I have a view controller which has a UIPickerView in it. I set that up by dragging it onto my NIB in IB, defined the property using IBOutlet, synthesized it, and then hooked it all up.

Every time I launch the view, it seems the number of UIPickerViews increases by one. I was under the assumption that I do not need to release this kind of thing myself, as I had assigned it to a property (using nonatomic, retain).

This is happening to all my UI stuff - buttons etc, not just the picker view. I was just using that as an example.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: The two places you need to release IB-connected objects are in `-viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

When the view is loaded all the items created from the NIB are retained for you and your IBOutlet pointers are initialized pointing to those retained subview objects.  You need to release those in viewDidUnload.  Are you doing that?

In viewDidUnload you should release all objects created from the NIB and set those pointer to nil.  You should also release those same object in dealloc.  [Example here.](https://github.com/progrmr/State-Hunt/blob/master/SettingsVC.m)

Comment: Oh, this is news to me - thank you! None of the books I've been reading have mentioned this at all. I thought that properties looked after memory management themselves. One question - Do I need to do this only for properties which are being used with IBOutlet, or all properties?

Comment: All objects that you create should be released when you are done with them.  In a view controller that is usually in viewDidUnload and dealloc.